# thead is not displaying

Tags: css

I have problem with my table. This table is primary for phones. When I have phone vertical, table is not showing thread, but when I have phone horizontally, it shows correctly.

Can anybody help me to display this table correctly on phones when phone is vertically?

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*table-layout: fixed;*/
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 60px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    /*//spodok tabulky*/
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    /*Hrubka ciary medzi riadkam*/
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: center;
    /*Pozicia textu*/
  }
  table td:before {
    /*
  * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
  content: attr(aria-label);
  */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  table td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!--<th>Poradie</th>-->
      <th>Císlo zákazky</th>
      <th>Pozícia</th>
      <th>Poradové císlo</th>
      <th>Stav</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Thank you for your response.

Comment: I mean <thead> not thread

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Considering that you are absolutely positioning & clipping the element, and give it a width of 0 and cut of the overflow ... I am not to sure what else you expected here?

Comment: what will happen if remove this `clip: rect(0 0 0 0);` from `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { table thead {`?

Comment: @ildflue Then it will still be hidden because of `width: 0px;` and `overflow: hidden;`, but the clip is of course one of the reasons this isn't working.

Comment: @RadoslavRác You might want to specify in detail what you consider a *"correctly"* displayed table header.

Comment: So my table collapse rows but table head is still on top. I wat to know if there is way to make this table head collapse with rows, but table head with correct head will be in same line like row. I mean <th>Císlo zákazky</th> will be in same line with <td>SomethigHere</td>

Comment: Here is what i mean: https://imgur.com/P1kz7C1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple fix. Remove `clip: rect(0 0 0 0);` and `width: 0px;`. Those lines hides the entire `thead` because the `@media` condition kicks in in portrait mode (narrower screen).

You might want to redo the entire `@media` section of your css - it's overall a bit weird. Maybe add a couple of details what you originally intended to do on narrow screens.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*table-layout: fixed;*/
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    height: 60px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    /*//spodok tabulky*/
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    /*Hrubka ciary medzi riadkam*/
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: center;
    /*Pozicia textu*/
  }
  table td:before {
    /*
  * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
  content: attr(aria-label);
  */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  table td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!--<th>Poradie</th>-->
      <th>Císlo zákazky</th>
      <th>Pozícia</th>
      <th>Poradové císlo</th>
      <th>Stav</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets just remove `thead` position and display rules.

Now we can see the `thead`. The you can add the remaining styles.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*table-layout: fixed;*/
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 60px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 0px;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    /*//spodok tabulky*/
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    /*Hrubka ciary medzi riadkam*/
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: center;
    /*Pozicia textu*/
  }
  table td:before {
    /*
  * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
  content: attr(aria-label);
  */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  table td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!--<th>Poradie</th>-->
      <th>Císlo zákazky</th>
      <th>Pozícia</th>
      <th>Poradové císlo</th>
      <th>Stav</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```